# how to access parameters in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i have this stored procedure in the update command of formview

```
DECLARE @ResultTelID int ; 
EXECUTE [CUSTOMER].[dbo].[uspUpdateClientTel] 
 @telephoneid
,@telephone
,@TelTypeID
,@DetailsTypeID
,@SortNo
,@ResultTelID OUTPUT
```

the first two varialbles are in the select query
but my doubt is how to pass values for the update parameters from the code behind

```
protected void FrmClient_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{        
    string strtel =((form1.FindControl("telephoneidLabel") as Label).Text)as string;

    SqlConnection conTel = new SqlConnection();
    conTel.ConnectionString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CUSTOMERConnectionString"]);
    conTel.Open();

    string strcmd = "SELECT tel_type_id, details_type_id, sort_no from TELEPHONE where tel_id =" + strtel;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcmd , conTel);
    SqlDataReader rdrTel = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while( rdrTel.Read())
    {
        int TeltypeID = (int)rdrTel["tel_type_id"];
        int DetailTypeID = (int)rdrTel["details_type_id"];
        Int16 Sort = (Int16)rdrTel["sort_no"];

        //sdsClient.UpdateParameters("TelTypeID").DefaultValue = (int)rdrTel["tel_type_id"];               
    }
    rdrTel.Close();
    conTel.Close();      
}
```

i want to know how to assign the value of the three prameters to the update command( sdsclient is the sqldatasource for the code)

thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter as you do with SQLCommand.. have an idea from follow code snippet.

```
    <asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server">
        <updateparameters>
                <asp:parameter name="Status" type="String" />
                <asp:parameter name="Comment" type="String" />
        </updateparameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

Update their value as:

```
  SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Status"].DefaultValue = "success";
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Comment"].DefaultValue = "something";
        SqlDataSource1.Update();
```

follow this [asp.net forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1303564.aspx/1) for more details

Comment: thx niranjan. i used  
            sdsClient.UpdateParameters["TelTypeID"].DefaultValue = rdrTel["tel_type_id"].ToString();